# miktex update causes issues "go to source/pdf" in TeXstudio

Tags: miktex, texstudio, auxiliary-files, forward-inverse-search

The most recent [MiKTeX update 21.6](https://miktex.org/announcement/miktex-21.6) resolves [an issue involving the aux directory](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/785) that seems to have changed the behavior of `-aux-directory=<filename>` to place the `.synctex.gz` files in the auxiliary folder rather than in the output directory (in this case the same location as the TeX file and PDF output since no `-output-directory` is specified) as it did before the update. This is confusing because in the linked issue, it's explained that SyncTeX files are indeed output files, not auxiliary files.

It would not be a concern except that TeXstudio needs the `synctex.gz` file in the same location as the TeX and PDF files for "go to source/pdf" to work (explained [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/818)). The command I'm running in TeXstudio 3.1.2 is

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory=C:\Users\matthew\math\auxtexfiles %.tex
```

on Windows 10. Is there a workaround to either tell TeXstudio to look in the auxiliary folder for the SyncTeX files or tell MiKTeX to place SyncTeX files with the TeX and PDF files as it did before the update?

Comment: According t the issue you linked synctex.gz shouldn't be moved to the aux-directory. If it is indeed moved to the aux-directory then you are experiencing the error the poster of the issue has noted. Have you tried specifying the output folder-option?

Comment: If I specify the output folder then every time I compile in TeXstudio, the output will go to that folder. I would like the synctex files to go to the same folder as the original tex file, which will be different depending on the location of the tex file.

Comment: There is now a GitHub issue: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/846

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found to work with TeXstudio on Windows 10 consists of editing the `PdfLaTeX` command within settings of TeXstudio so that it resembles the following:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory=build -output-directory=./ %.tex
```

where `build` is my directory for auxiliary files and `./` specifies the current root directory where output files should be placed, e.g. .pdf,.synctex.gz, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! I still think it is a bug since I don't believe MikTeX intends to require an output directory specified for this behavior, though this is only a guess.